# Имеет ли смысл использовать distinct и group by в одном запросе Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация-запросов

Допустим у нас есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  x int(10) NOT NULL,
  y int(10) NOT NULL,
  z int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
```

и имеется запрос

```
select distinct(table.*) from table group by x;
```

Имеет ли смысл в данной конструкции использовать group by? Что подсказывает мне логика.
Мы в таблице записи группируем по полю х, при этом остальные поля у нас будут в каждом запросе случайны из группы. Например в запросе

```
select max(id), x, y, z from table group by x;
```

Для каждой группы x найдется максимальный id, но вот поля y, z  не будут иметь отношений к строке с максимальным id. Т.е. смысла их выводить особого нет. А если рассмотреть первый запрос, то смысл мне не особо понятен. У нас строки так и так уже уникальны. Возможно я где-то не прав и ошибаюсь?

Comment: Оба запроса синтаксически ошибочны и дают недетерминированный результат, если разрешить их выполнение. Обсуждать что-либо с ними связанное не имеет смысла.

Comment: *Имеет ли смысл использовать distinct и group by в одном запросе Mysql?* В теории одновременное использование может иметь смысл - в случае, когда выражение группировки "шире" списка полей выходного набора. Правда, я не могу навскидку преобразовать это в реальную задачу...

Comment: "Оба запроса синтаксически ошибочны и дают недетерминированный результат"(с) с синтаксисом вроде бы проблем нет. А вот результат действительно будет не предсказуемый потому и вопрос.

Comment: @Akina, Я тут подумал, может идея запроса в том, что бы сначала сгрупировать по признаку x, а потом убрать дубли y,z. Т.е. какой-то такой запрос должен быть select distinct(y,z) from table group by x;

Comment: Хотя можно тот же запрос без группировки сделать и выхлоп получится тот же самый.